# Flutter ListView.Builder Optional Parameter for Firestore attribute

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: latestPosts.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: Spinner());
          }
  ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {     
              var ownerUid = snapshot.data?.docs[index]['ownerUid'];
              String? poll1 = snapshot.data?.docs[index]['poll1'];
              return FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('users')
                          .doc(ownerUid)
                          .get(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot asyncsnapshot) {
                        if (asyncsnapshot.hasData) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [ Text(ownerUid), Text(poll1 ?? '')]);                       
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                            child: null,
                        );
                     }
                  },
              );
            },
          );  
      
    }
 )
```

I am trying to make "poll1" String an optional value however I get '*Bad state: field "poll1" does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform*' message for Firestore documents that don't have the "poll1" parameter. How can I make this value optional so I don't get the error?

Comment: Use `get('poll1')` rather than `['poll1']`. Note that this error has been covered quite regularly before, so also check https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+firestore+Bad+state%3A+field+does+not+exist+within+the+DocumentSnapshotPlatform